# Xamarin Text-To-Speech Total Time

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to find out how to implement a very simple progress bar for the [Text-to-Speech example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/text-to-speech), but until now I have found no clues. There are few questions, see some related [for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872243/calculate-total-duration-of-text-to-speech-like-mediaplayer), [for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668291/calculate-total-speech-time-in-ios), and [another for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458127/how-to-covert-text-of-words-per-minute-to-speech-rate-using-avspeechutterance), but no answer on Xamarin's side.

Is there a way to retrieve the **total time it will take to convert a text to a speech**?

I am open also to very creative pre-processed solution, like saving the results of the speech to a file (with the native speech synthesis).

Hints/Suggestions?

Comment: I would assume that depending on the length and complexity of the text that is needing to be spoken, the speech framework will most likely not be able to give an exact time. I would suggest using an `ActivityIndicator` to show an indication that the text is being converted.

Comment: I think you're right, but what about an *approximate* timing? I would be happy even with multiples of, let's say, 10s ("circa 40s" that can be 30s or 50s, I wouldn't mind). Or even in minutes (circa one, two, ...). That would be awesome.